# Linux shell su -c 'sed' command

Tags: linux, shell

```
$ sudo su - root -c 'sed -i '$a\PermitRootLogin yes' etc/ssh/sshd_config'
```

after run the command,it always displays

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

and

```
$ sudo su - root -c "sed -i '$a\PermitRootLogin yes' etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

will display

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated address regex
```

how should I modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes don't nest. Since you have single quotes in the sed command, use double quotes for the outer set. Then make sure to escape `\$a` so it's not interpreted as a shell variable named `$a`.

```
sudo su - root -c "sed -i '\$a\\PermitRootLogin yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
```

You can avoid the quoting problems by getting rid of the whole `su -` business, though. `sudo` already gives you root access, no need to combine it with `su`. Once you do that you no longer need two sets of quotes and the problem disappears entirely.

```
sudo sed -i '$a\PermitRootLogin yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

By the way, sed is a bit heavy handed if all you want to do is append a line of text. It will copy the original file to a temporary file, add the line to the copy, and then replace the original with the copy. You can avoid this overhead by using `>>` or `tee -a`, either of which will append the line in place without all the copying.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config'
```

```
sudo tee -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config <<< 'PermitRootLogin yes' > /dev/null
```